# Share session from apache to tomcat on different servers

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, drupal

Hi I was wondering is it possible to share sessions from an apache server where drupal 6 is installed to a tomcat on another server? I want to authenticate a user to a tomcat webapp when they login to drupal. I've read documentation on it but they all require the the apache server and tomcat server to be on the same domain.

Comment: interested in the answers you get , plus what causes such requirement  ?

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat use

```
memcached-session-manager
```

in apache/php, set memcached for sessions handling.

You need a memcached instance that both servers can access, or you can set-up a memcached server on either of the servers.

You will need php5-memcached or php-pecl-memcache depending on the linux repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database for session handling. The database should be accessible to both apache and tomcat.